# How to Unpickle a classes objects correctly?

Tags: python

Currently have my code working fine except for when I unpickle the data. The program currently reads lines from a `.txt` file, each line in the `.txt` file has 5 variables that are assigned to a classes objects. However when I unpickle the data, it has only pickled the first line of text from the `.txt` file, and not everything.

I have tried several different ways of pickling the data, but I feel that my be where my problem lies.

Here is the first part of my code, with the opening of the `.txt` file and pickling of data:

```
class players:
    def __init__(players,lastName,firstName,games,total,position):
        players.lastName = lastName
        players.firstName = firstName
        players.games = games
        players.total = total
        players.position = position

# Transfer Team Details
def transferDetails():
    exists = False
    while exists == False:
        try:
            file = input("\nPlease enter the text file name: ")
            text_file = open(file + ".txt", "r")
            binary_File = open(file + ".dat", "wb")
            exists = True
            for line in text_file.readlines():
                lastName,firstName,games,total,position = [str(i.strip()) for i in line.split(',')] # Assign here
                lastName = lastName[0:20]# Truncate
                lastName = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z]', '', lastName)# Cleaning
                firstName = firstName[0:20]# Truncate
                firstName = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z]', '', firstName)# Cleaning
                # Changing position to default if not set correctly
                if position != "Forward" and position != "Centre" and position != "Guard" :
                    position = "Guard"
                ### Changing games to valid number: 0-200
                games = float(games)
                if games < 0 :
                    games = 0
                elif games > 200 :
                    games = 0
                ### Changing total points value to valid number: 0-1000
                total = float(total)###
                if total < 0 :
                    total = 0
                elif total > 1000 :
                    total = 0
                pickle.dump(lastName, binary_File)
                pickle.dump(firstName, binary_File)
                pickle.dump(games, binary_File)
                pickle.dump(total, binary_File)
                pickle.dump(position, binary_File)
                binary_File.close
                ###TESTING ONLY###
                print("Last Name: ", lastName)
                print("First Name : ", firstName)
                print("Games played: ", games)
                print("Total points: ", total)
                print("Position: ", position)
                print("\n\n")
                ###TESTING ONLY###
        ### File not found
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("File not found")
```

And here is the code for un-pickling the data:

```
def listPlayers():
    #Input Code Here
    file2 = input("\nPlease enter the binary file name: ")
    with open(file2 + ".dat", 'rb') as binary_File:
        lastName = pickle.load(binary_File)
        firstName = pickle.load(binary_File)
        games = pickle.load(binary_File)
        total = pickle.load(binary_File)
        position = pickle.load(binary_File)
        print(lastName)
        print(firstName)
        print(games)
        print(total)
        print(position)
```

Here is the output if I decide to un-pickle the data through a function. Note there should be 4 separate players here, not just one, and the original `.txt` file has 4 lines of txt:

```
Please enter the binary file name: test1
bob
billy
10.0
40.0
Guard
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you decide to use pickle here? Based on the use case here it seems like json would be a better option than pickle, although I understand if its just an example and your real use case requires pickle

Comment: The `listPlayers()` function does not have a loop that would allow it to read more than one player.

Comment: Since I am a student, all we have learnt so far is pickling and shelving of data. I thought a pickle would be ideal for this, however it may not be the case?

Comment: How would I add a loop to the function to make it read more then one? Because once I unpickle the data, I need to do more calculations with it @JohnGordon

Answer (score 0):

The `pickle` module implements binary protocols for serializing and de-serializing **a** Python object structure. (according to [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html))

That is to say, you should `pickle` the object(dict/list) only **ONCE**.

---

for the pickling function, modify as following:

```
while exists == False:
    try:
        file = input("\nPlease enter the text file name: ")
        text_file = open(file + ".txt", "r")
        binary_File = open(file + ".dat", "wb")
        exists = True
        ## initiate a list to store all player_info to-be dump
        players_list = []
        for line in text_file.readlines():
            ...
            ...
            ## use your Player class
            players_list.append(Players(lastName,firstName,games,total,position))
            print("Last Name: ", lastName)
            print("First Name : ", firstName)
            print("Games played: ", games)
            print("Total points: ", total)
            print("Position: ", position)
        ## dump the list of Player objects into the file after the for-loop
        pickle.dump(players, binary_File)
        binary_File.close
```

---

for the un-pickling function:

```
with open(file2 + ".dat", 'rb') as binary_File:
    ## retrieve the list of Player objects
    players_list = pickle.load(binary_File)
    for player in players_list:
        print(player.lastName)
        print(player.firstName)
        print(player.games)
        print(player.total)
        print(player.position)
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the ```players.append(Player(lastName,firstName,games,total,position))``` line, it causes an error and doesn't pickle

Comment: Gives me the error: ```TypeError: 'list' object is not callable```

Comment: I think its a problem on the naming of the list, changed it to `players_list`

Comment: Yes that seemed to have worked, however I think some of the un pickling code needs re working as it isnt working?

Comment: Btw, FYI, the convention for naming a class is to capitalise the first letter (`class Players:`) and to use `self.xxx` instead of `players.xxx` in referencing the object itself.

Comment: un-pickling part updated, if the codes are working then the question is probably completed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245772/discussion-between-ytung-dev-and-emilio).